# Black screen when booting to Windows 10 from the boot menu

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot

My laptop used to boot Windows 10 only. I recently changed it to dual-boot with Ubuntu. When I turn on the PC, it shows the boot menu where I can choose which system to start. I'm able to boot into Ubuntu without a problem, but I realized that Windows 10 can't boot properly: when I choose to boot from Windows 10 (in the boot menu), the screen stays black with a white "_" that shows on the top left corner, and I can't boot to Windows 10 at all.

What should I do to be able to boot Windows 10?

Answer (score -1):

I also had same issue ..so i went to computer shop and he told me that because of huge moisture in air(it was rainy season) components inside laptop gets moist too ..so he opened my laptop and blew some hot air with heat gun on its component and my laptop's screen started working again ..
I thought this might help you

another issue : with the ram stick

Comment: This does not explain why booting into Ubuntu works.